# debian 9 installation on HP DL20 Gen9

Tags: installation, debian

I have installed debian 9.3 on HP DL20 Gen9. When Debian 9.3 start, what happen is that the screen of the system appear like on the picture after the grub goes. any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try booting your computer up in safe mode from Grub. Install updates and restart.

If it happens again you probably need to configure your graphics card for your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. I used "nomodeset on the boot", and the screen appear normaly. I have used another tty2 and i get connected with the shell.

> nano /etc/default/grub

i find this:

> ```
>  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
> ```

and i have changed it to this:

> ```
>  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Debian 9, when in the `Software selection` menu,
don't enable **Debian Desktop Environment**. If you need a desktop environment, simply enable certain Desktop environments.

In this case, I'm using Cinnamon. Until now there are no problems.

Thanks.